# Key Listner in a console application using multithreading

Tags: c#

I have to create this console based application and I have this problem:
I have created something like a KeyListener using multithreading (can't do simple loop, because there is a second thread running simultaneously).
And the loop in a thread needs to check if pressed key is an integer.

What is that I don't understand?

The way I get this: there is an infinite loop within the thread that tries to capture the input and if the `input == 1` it writes text in the console.
What am I missing?

```
static void KeyRead()
{            
    do
    {
        int i = (int) Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        if (i == 1) {
           Console.Out.Write("Key 1 pressed");
        }
    } while (true);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread keyListner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(KeyRead));
    keyListner.Start();                   
}
```

Comment: _"What is that i don't understand?"_ -- What is your question? What _specifically_ is the code doing that you don't want it to do and you can't figure out how to fix?

Comment: It does basically nothing. That's the problem. It's just like there was no "if" statement.
What should be done to make it execute the code after if statement?
I start the application, I press "1" and nothing happens although it should write "Key 1 pressed".

Comment: Your program wouldn't work even without the thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955029/how-do-i-convert-a-console-readkey-to-an-int-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

*KeyChar* returns value of type *char* and casting *char* to *int* returns unicode value representing that character. But character `'1'` have [unicode value](https://unicode-table.com/en/) 49, not 1. So you have to modify condition to compare *i* to be eqaual to 49 instead of 1.

```
static void KeyRead()
{
    do
    {
        int i = (int)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        if (i == 49)
        {
            Console.Out.Write("Key 1 pressed");
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

But it is even beter to avoid this integer conversion altogether and compare character directly:

```
static void KeyRead()
{
    do
    {
        char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        if (c == '1')
        {
            Console.Out.Write("Key 1 pressed");
        }
    } while (true);
}
```